# how to view text di viewHolder

Tags: android, android-viewholder

I want to display a text in my view holder but it doesn't appear, only the email text appears while the others don't. how to make it appear?
this is my view holder adapter

```
    public TextView teksemail;
    public TextView namanya;
    public TextView golongannya;
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public listOnlineViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);

        teksemail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.teksemail);
        namanya = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namanya);
        golongannya = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.golongan);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }
```

this is my information class

```
public class information {

    public String email;
    public String nama;
    public String nalamat;
    public String noTelpon;
    public String golDar;
    public String imageUrl;

    public information() {

    }

    public information(String email, String nama, String nalamat, String noTelpon, String golDar, String imageUrl) {
        this.email = email;
        this.nama = nama;
        this.nalamat = nalamat;
        this.noTelpon = noTelpon;
        this.golDar = golDar;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public String getNalamat() {
        return nalamat;
    }

    public String getNoTelpon() {
        return noTelpon;
    }

    public String getGolDar() {
        return golDar;
    }
```

and this is my code viewholder in my activity

```
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fused;
    public TextView goldar, nama, telpon, alamat;
    DatabaseReference onlineRef, currentUserRef, counterRef, locationsDatabase,databaseReference;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<information, listOnlineViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    int waktu = 3000;
    RecyclerView list;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_online);

        list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listonline);
        list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        nama = findViewById(R.id.teksnama);
        alamat = findViewById(R.id.teksalamat);
        telpon = findViewById(R.id.tekstelpon);
        goldar = findViewById(R.id.teksgoldar);

            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                fused = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

                //databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("data");
                locationsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("locations");
                onlineRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(".info/connected");
                counterRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("lastOnline");
                currentUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("lastOnline").
                        child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("data");

                //load user info
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String namanya = dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue(String.class);
                        String addnya = dataSnapshot.child("alamat").getValue(String.class);
                        String nonya = dataSnapshot.child("noTelpon").getValue(String.class);
                        String goldarnya = dataSnapshot.child("golDar").getValue(String.class);
                        nama.setText(namanya);
                        alamat.setText(addnya);
                        telpon.setText(nonya);
                        goldar.setText(goldarnya);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        displayLocation();

                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(listOnline.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                                (listOnline.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(listOnline.this, new String[] {
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                            },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                        } else {
                            if (checkPlayService()) {
                                buildGoogleApiClient();
                                createLocationRequest();
                                displayLocation();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }, waktu);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setUpSystem();
                        //load all user from firebase
                        updateList();
                    }
                }, waktu);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hai Resipienku!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(listOnline.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                        (listOnline.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(listOnline.this, new String[] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

                    fused.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            Toast.makeText(listOnline.this, "get your location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        setUpSystemResipien();
                        //load all user from firebase
                        updateList();
                    }
                }, waktu);
            }
        }


/*    private void loadUserInfo(String email) {
        Query userLocation = locationsDatabase.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
        userLocation.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                /*for (DataSnapshot posSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    information track = posSnapshot.getValue(information.class);
                    String namanya = track.getNama();
                    nama.setText(track.getNama());
                    alamat.setText(track.getNalamat());
                    goldar.setText(track.getGolDar());
                    telpon.setText(track.getNoTelpon());
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
*/
    private void getLastLocation () {
        fused.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                locationsDatabase.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(new tracking(
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()
                        ,FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
                        , String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())
                        , String.valueOf(location.getLongitude())
                        , nama.getText().toString()
                        , alamat.getText().toString().trim()
                        ,goldar.getText().toString().trim()
                        ,telpon.getText().toString().trim()));
                Toast.makeText(listOnline.this, "get location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

     private void updateList() {
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<information, listOnlineViewHolder>(
                information.class, R.layout.user_online,
                listOnlineViewHolder.class,
                counterRef) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final listOnlineViewHolder viewHolder, final information model, int position) {
                viewHolder.teksemail.setText(model.getEmail());
                viewHolder.namanya.setText(model.getNama());

                // Query userInfromation = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(model.getEmail());
              /*  userInfromation.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot posSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        information info = posSnapshot.getValue(information.class);
                        String name = dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue(String.class);
                        String goldar = dataSnapshot.child("golDar").getValue(String.class);
                        viewHolder.namanya.setText(name);
                        viewHolder.golongannya.setText(goldar);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

               */

                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                        fused.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                                Intent map = new Intent(listOnline.this, trackingMaps.class);
                                map.putExtra("email", model.getEmail());
                                map.putExtra("lat", location.getLatitude());
                                map.putExtra("lnt", location.getLongitude());
                                startActivity(map);

                            }
                        });
                        //  }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    //buat setup untuk resipien

    private void setUpSystem() {
        onlineRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class)) {
                    currentUserRef.onDisconnect().removeValue();
                    counterRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).
                            setValue(new user(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), "online"
                            ,nama.getText().toString(),goldar.getText().toString()));
                    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                counterRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            user us = postSnapshot.getValue(user.class);
                           // Log.d("LOG", ""+us.getEmail()+"is"+us.getNamadia());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

I have tried to find a solution but could not find it. I really hope you can help me. thank you!

this is my XML which is contained your textviews

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="test@gmail.com"
            android:id="@+id/teksemail"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/namanya"
            android:text="nama"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/teksemail"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/golongan"
            android:text="golongan"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/namanya"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: share your XML which is contained your textviews.

Comment: I have added XML which contains textviews

Comment: Are you sure model.getNama() is not empty? Print your model in log to be sure that data is exist.

Comment: i dont know, I will try it first

Comment: i've tried it and model.getName() is empty. why empty? @EugeneTroyanskii

Comment: @EwaSaputra i don't know any details about you Firebase storage. My blind suggestion is that in you storage your name field named like 'name' but not 'nama' that's why your 'nama' field is empty. Any way it's  another question and current problem is solved.Btw user only English in you code to simplify help requests. Keep in mind that some day in your project could be involved some one else who don't know you language. Also use java code convention.

Comment: @Eugene Troyanskii ok i understand, thanks for the help...